what is the issue when i tried to add a pretuned t5 model to the project from github
I git-cloned a project and did all the installation. The website also launched. But I think I couldn't connect to the two files (t5-base-full-seeded.ckpt and t5-small-full-seeded.ckpt) because the project is not showing any results when I try to summarize or search.
Should I make/add my local path of the files in any of the files (app.py or finetuner.py)
how do I resolve this, connect the ckpt files, and make the app function properly?
I have downloaded the two ckpt files and added them to the root of the repository.
I expect someone to rectify the above problem so that it works properly. It's kinda an emergency.

did you see this part of the readme? You need to download the pre-tuned t5-model checkpoints and place them in the root of the repository

yes i did that ! i have added the 2 files into the project folder along with app.py and finetuner.py. but still it isnt working.
